# UPDATE with isNull

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server,

if the inner select doesn't have a matching criteria, then I need to update Field1 with blank instead of null.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Field1=(
    SELECT Field2
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table2.Field3 = Table1.Field4
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking here. You've even referenced the correct function (`ISNULL`) in your title for what your goal is, so what is your actual question?

Comment: What about the case where `Field1` already has a non-null, non-blank value? Do you want to overwrite that value blindly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null expression in a list. You can keep most of your original query, by using COALESCE() to replace any NULL from that query with an empty string.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Field1=COALESCE((
    SELECT Field2
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table2.Field3 = Table1.Field4
), '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try like this -

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Field1 = ISNULL(b.Field2,'')
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON b.Field3 = a.Field4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reference another table using SQL Server's `UPDATE ... FROM ...` syntax:

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     field1 = COALESCE(t2.field2, '')
FROM    Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
        Table2 t2
ON      t2.Field3 = t1.Field4
```

Comment: Needs to be LEFT join for this do what the OP is looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.Field1=isnull(T2.Field2,'')
from Table1 T1 left join Table2 T2
    ON T2.Field3 = T1.Field4
```